# Trying to add some form of validation to a user input in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a simple program in C# that is capable of reading a .TXT file.  So far I am able to display an error message if the incorrect file location is typed, however when I input a correct file path the program displays nothing... Any advice/guidance would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

```
`using System;
 using System.IO;

 class ReadFromFile
 {
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Welcome to Decrypter (Press any key to       begin)");
    Console.ReadKey ();

    //User selects file they wish to decrypt
    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    string path;


    Console.WriteLine ("\nPlease type the path to your file");
    path = Console.ReadLine ();


 try
  {
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {

    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    System.IO.StreamReader file = 
        new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (line);
        counter++;
    }

    file.Close();

    // Suspend the screen.
    Console.ReadLine();
      }
}
catch (Exception)
{
Console.WriteLine("The value you entered is incorrect.");
 }
}
```

}`

Comment: This could be easily spotted if you just try to follow this code with the debugger. ! means NOT

Comment: Theres no debugger in Notepad ++

Comment: Is there anything in the file?

Comment: Why are you develoing in Notepad++ ?

Comment: Then use LinqPAD, or download the free edition of Visual Studio. As a programmer you should choose the tools that helps in your workings (by the way, Notepad++ has a plugin for that CScript or something like that)

Comment: Thanks Steve..... I see the error.... I've spent hours staring at it. Thanks again.

Comment: Again, this is just the beginning. If you want to be serious about programming then use the right tools

Comment: How about Visual Studio Code... (I'm using a Mac)

Comment: Never tried, it seems to be a good choice

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{


     class ReadFromFile
     {
         static void Main()
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Decrypter (Press any key to       begin)");
             Console.ReadKey();

             //User selects file they wish to decrypt
             int counter = 0;
             string line;
             string path = "";

             try
             {
                 while (true)
                 {
                     if (!File.Exists(path))
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine("\nPlease type the path to your file");
                         path = Console.ReadLine();
                     }
                     else
                     {

                         // Read the file and display it line by line.
                         System.IO.StreamReader file =
                             new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
                         while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                         {
                             Console.WriteLine(line);
                             counter++;
                         }

                         file.Close();
                         break;
                     }
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("The value you entered is incorrect.");
             }

         }
     }
  }
​
```